# error al subir proyecto a git git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git

**Me da este error** `git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)` cuando pongo git push -u origin main.

**He probado de crear** las claves ssh y ponerlas en github y en el servidor pero no funciona

Comment: Pues así de primeras... ese `git@github.com` me escama un montón. Lo normal es que ahí estuviese tu nombre de usuario. Tienes configurada la cuenta bien?

Comment: Te recomiendo leer detenidamente la guía de resolución de problemas de GitHub para este error [**Error: Permiso denegado (publickey)**](https://docs.github.com/es/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey) así podrás resolver tu problema ya que incluye de forma detallada las posibles causas.

Answer (score 1):

Supongamos que creaste un par de llaves, como dices en tu pregunta, y pusiste la llave privada en tu carpeta `~/.ssh` con permiso `600`. Luego subiste la llave pública a github en la sección "SSH and GPG keys" de tu perfil.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y vamos a suponer que generaste tus llaves usando OpenSSL o ssh-keygen. Por ejemplo una llave con algoritmo `ed25519`

```
  ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "david@localhost"  -N "" -q -a 100   -f "clave_david.key"
```

Luego moverías ese archivo a `~/.ssh/` y en tu `~/.ssh/config` pondrías una referencia a esa llave:

```
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    Port 22
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/clave_david.key
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Lo importante es la última línea.

```
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Ahí dice: "cuando te conectes a github, usa esta llave y no pruebes el resto de las llaves que tengo para bitbucket, gitlab y mis servidores personales".

Esto, porque el comportamiento natural de ssh es probar todas tus llaves, y al tercer intento el servidor te rechaza por `too many attempts`.

Al poner `IdentitiesOnly` en cambio, solamente probará con la llave `identity` (esa es la llave por defecto, siempre) y la nueva.

> ssh git@github.com -v

Responde

```
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ffflabs/.ssh/identity RSA SHA256:F80CIq+lbhtXPCrcd3yVZZ04vpA54IBdd7MylP2HDnM explicit
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/ffflabs/.ssh/clave_david.key ED25519 SHA256:1kh9FFWvcm+S75qVsCNIXiSLojVqnfnMs7Yeyiqudhg explicit

Hi ffflabs! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to github.com closed.
```